# Background image for iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
    <META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
    <META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
    <div style="background-image: url('images1.jpg');width:800;height:300;border:1px solid black">
    <iframe scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true" name="main" style="width:100%;height:90%;"> </iframe>
    </div>

    </BODY>
    </HTML>
```

I need to add background image to iframe. so i tried to add background image to iframe but i cant .. so i did it using div tag as above.
Its works properly in firefox but not in IE. Please help me if u known this

Comment: Shouldn't you be defining your background image in the page that you are displaying within the IFRAME?

Comment: I assume you are using a browser < IE9?

Comment: @ Neurofluxation : ya i am using IE8

Answer (score 2):

You can with background-image in css

```
iframe{
background:url(http://www.hindsightfishing.com/images/waves_bg.jpg) no-repeat left top
}​
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/9tndk/

Comment: Hi sowmya, thanks for your answer...but its not working for me..I just added the CSS in my HTML(Which i posted above)..Even in demo link its not works

Comment: Where is your demo and r u sure that your image path is correct?? http://jsfiddle.net/vE7Be/1/ Check this demo, I have add bg image in your style (inline css)

Comment: <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<STYLE>
iframe{
background:url('images1.jpg') no-repeat left top
}
</STYLE>

<BODY>
 <div style="background:url(images1.jpeg) no-repeat left top;width:800;height:300;border:1px solid black">
    <iframe scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="true" name="main" style="width:100%;height:90%;"> </iframe>
    </div>
</BODY>
</HTML>   //I just have this HTML and images1.jpeg in same folder.Its not works 4 me

Comment: Even i cant see your demo works fine .. i just able to see blank Iframe.. image not gets displayed.. FYI, i am using IE8